# how to solve second order differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been solving some differential equations but I got stuck on this one:

$x^2y''(x) -3xy'(x) + 5y(x) = 0$

All the methods I used before wont work and now Im just clueless on how to solve that one.. any advice?

Comment: Can you find its adjoint equation?

Comment: If your'e not familiar with Euler-Cauchy differential equations, I would recommend reading http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $r(r-1)+3r+5=0$ then the $x^r$s are solutions.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** It is [*Euler-Cauchy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) type, so try$$y = x^m$$